# wxPython: Hide a widget and remove the leftover space

Tags: python, wxpython, hide, sizer

I want to hide a widget in a sizer and not leave an empty space.
I do not want to remove the widget, because I want to show it again later.

Is there a way to hide a widget and have the shown widgets after it move over one space to fill the empty spot?

Here is a simple example of a space being left:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 3, 0, 0)

        a = wx.Button(self, -1, 'a')
        b = wx.Button(self, -1, 'b')
        c = wx.Button(self, -1, 'c')

        sizer.Add(a, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer.Add(b, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer.Add(c, 0, 0, 0)

        b.Hide()

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Remove Spaces")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have to use `wx.GridSizer`? Because it will give you a **fixed layout**, so even you hide a control the grid will still have that space displayed.

Have you considered using [`wx.GridBagSizer`](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GridBagSizer-class.html)? Try this one:

```
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

        self.a = wx.Button(self, -1, 'a')
        self.b = wx.Button(self, -1, 'b')
        self.c = wx.Button(self, -1, 'c')
        self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_clicked)

        self.sizer.Add(self.a, pos=(0, 0))
        self.sizer.Add(self.b, pos=(0, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.c, pos=(0, 2))

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def button_clicked(self, event):
        if self.b.IsShown():
            self.b.Hide()
        else:
            self.b.Show()
        self.parent.Fit()
```

Using `FlexGridSizer`:

```
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 3, 0, 0)

        self.a = wx.Button(self, -1, 'a')
        self.b = wx.Button(self, -1, 'b')
        self.c = wx.Button(self, -1, 'c')
        self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_clicked)

        self.sizer.Add(self.a)
        self.sizer.Add(self.b)
        self.sizer.Add(self.c)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def button_clicked(self, event):
        if self.b.IsShown():
            self.b.Hide()
        else:
            self.b.Show()
        self.parent.Fit()
```

Comment: Your example does remove the empty space, but as far as I can see, this will only work for a Bag Sizer.

Is there a way to remove empty spaces *regardless* of the sizer type (grid sizer, flex grid sizer, bag sizer, etc.)?

Comment: As far as i know, `GridSizer` is pretty static. You would need to readd that last button to the sizer in the second position.

Comment: What about a `FlexGridSizer`?

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because you did show a way to remove empty space, even if it is not using a different sizer.

Comment: @Kade I've added the one with `FlexGridSizer` as you mentioned.

Comment: @ Selçuk Cihan It looks like this only works if you hide all items in the column, regardless of it being a `Flex Sizer` or a `BagSizer`. The `Grid Sizer` does not do this, because each 'slot' is the same size.

I do not think there is a way to make the elements shift over one space to fill empty spaces without re-positioning everything in a `Bag Sizer`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kade sure if there are multiple rows and you only hide an item in one row, then it will not cause the empty space to collapse because otherwise the items in other rows would be affected.

Comment: A more recent answer says that instead of Fit(), you should call Layout() on the topmost container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540783