# wxWidgets - Hide/Show contents of of a `boxsizer` on button click

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm very new to `C++`, only 2 weeks, before this, I was learning python and used `Tkinter` to make a music player, as a practice project, until recently I discovered `wxWidgets` and used `wxPython` then I switched to C++, as I really wanted to learn `C++`. I have this playlist `listbox` widget, which I have in the same frame inside a `panel` widget, and its own `boxsizer` widget, I want it so that it hides and shows, on a button click, and main window resizes accordingly automatically. I searched around for how to do that, I did find `Show()` and `Hide()`, and I was able to achieve the effect I want, but the main window does not resize correctly, it stretches weirdly and shows the playlist in wrong size.

The function for button that hides the playlist looks like this

```
void Frame::Playlist(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    if (playlistButton->GetValue() == 1)
    {
        hboxSizer8->Show(true);
        hboxSizer9->Show(true);
        hboxSizer8->Layout();
        hboxSizer9->Layout();
        vboxSizer->Layout();
        panel->SetSizerAndFit(vboxSizer, true);
    }
    else
    {
        hboxSizer8->Show(false);
        hboxSizer9->Show(false);
        hboxSizer8->Layout();
        hboxSizer9->Layout();
        vboxSizer->Layout();
        panel->SetSizerAndFit(vboxSizer, true);
    }
}
```

and the button is set up like this

```
    playlistButton = new wxToggleButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Playlist"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    playlistButton->Bind(wxEVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, &Frame::Playlist, this);
```

I'm adding a GIF to explain the problem better.
[image: musicApp]

Also is there a widget or some feature in `wxWidgets` that can make a separate window, so I can like make a separate window that holds my playlist instead of same window for everything, and they can like snap together and join, when user brings them close to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Layout()` on the topmost sizer after you `Hide()/Show()`.

Also, take a look at the auidemo and check the documentation about wxAUI* classes.

Sizers are not windows. You should call `Hide()/Show()` on the wxListBox only and then call `Layout()` on the topmost sizer.

Comment: The top widget is a panel, and topmost sizer is `vboxsizer`, and it has bunch of other horizontal and vertical sizers, which I am already calling the `Layout()` for. I tried adding `panel->Layout()` but its still same.

Comment: I removed `Show()` on the sizers and instead set the individual widgets i.e, `listbox` and the buttons below it to hide, and then I called the topmost sizer which `vboxsizer`, but it still same.

Comment: @apoorv569, can you make an SSCE? Also what wx version and OS you are using? Did you compile it yourself? What compiler?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what SSCE is. I am using Arch Linux, and I use meson and ninja, with GCC. I downloaded wxWidgets from the Arch repo, package called `wxgtk3` which is on version 3.0.

Comment: @apoorv569, it is self-contained compilable example or a patch to one of the samples provided with wxWidgets. Make you code as small as possible so that someone can verify that.issue and possibly correct your code.

Comment: My whole program is only 1 file mainly, there are 4 files, 2 are `.hpp` and 2 `.cpp` one of them only has a class inherited from `wxApp` to run the program, the other one has the actual GUI and function related to all widgets, and is only about 550 lines. If you want a link, I can share it here. And maybe tell you the relevant part to look at. Or maybe I can remove the un-related things from the file, and shorten it even more, then share perhaps.

Comment: @apoorv569, please make it bare minimum that will allow to compile and run the code in order to see the problem. Or as I said - try to reproduce it in one of the wxWidgets samples - in this case `minimal` would be best.

Comment: I have trimmed the `frame.cpp` file, from 550 lines to 154 lines, now it just contains the base GUI, and the function for the button that toggles `Hide()` and `Show()` for playlist. You can compile it by running the script inside the project folder `build.sh`, you need meson and ninja installed. Here is the link for the tarball - https://mega.nz/folder/ZhJzVa4C#30uGPDVVMCNdcqIz170U_Q

Comment: Were you able to find the problem. I am still facing this issue.

Comment: @apoorv569, could you please post the source code here. If I understand the problem correctly, the code should be around 50 lines long. I don't know that website and downloading the archive might be dangerous.

Comment: You can check the relevant code here - https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/cpp-projects/-/blob/master/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/src/SmallPlayer.cpp#L357

Comment: @apoorv569, I looked at the code. Couple of things. Why do use call `Hide()/Show()` and then `Layout()` 2 times? Also - any reason to call `SetSizerAndFit()` every time you hide/show controls?

Comment: Those `Layout()` are for different sizers. No reason for using `SetSizerAndFIt()` I was trying it out to see if that helps.

Comment: @apoorv569, get rid of the first one and call `Layout()` on the topmost sizer only. And remove that `SetgSizerAndFit()` call. Also, look at the documentation for the functionality you use in the program. It will save you a lot of troubles.

Comment: Yes, its working now, I'm only calling `Layout()` on top sizer. I think calling `Layout()` on other sizer were resizing the top sizer in other ways, hence the weird stretched UI. Thank you!. I do look at documentation whole project I made with the help of documentation only.

Comment: @apoorv569, I mentioned the docs because you were using `SetSizerAndFit()` call. And I'm glad it works.

Comment: Yea, that was just my guess to use `SetSizerAndFit()`, I just forgot to remove it, before uploading.